# Load thumbnail image from video saved at NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation, ios5, nsdocumentdirectory

I use the following code to get an image from a video at given path.

```
- (UIImage*) thumbnailImageForVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    NSParameterAssert(asset);
    AVAssetImageGenerator *assetImageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    assetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    assetImageGenerator.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeEncodedPixels;

    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = NULL;
    CFTimeInterval thumbnailImageTime = time;
    NSError *thumbnailImageGenerationError = nil;
    thumbnailImageRef = [assetImageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(thumbnailImageTime, 60) actualTime:NULL error:&thumbnailImageGenerationError];

    if (!thumbnailImageRef)
        NSLog(@"thumbnailImageGenerationError %@", thumbnailImageGenerationError);

    UIImage *thumbnailImage = thumbnailImageRef ? [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef]  : nil;
    previewImage = thumbnailImage;

    return thumbnailImage;
}
```

However this is not working for a video saved in a NSDocumentDirectory. Cant we access the NSDocumentDIrectory using NSURL? If not any alternative. The main idea is to show the thumbnail of an image saved in document directory and later allow it to upload to sever. This can be a temp directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Worked when you use NSURL *outputURL =  [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];